# What is the difference between running a shell installer inside the directory and outside?

Tags: docker

I want to recreate my server setup with docker,
Previously I used Ubuntu 16.04 in the digital ocean to install a custom Firebird server. And I want to recreate it using docker `ubuntu:16.04` image.

To install the server the vendor provides a [install.sh](http://deluxeaccounting.com/download/accurate/v5/fb64linux/FirebirdACCURATE-2.5.4.amd64.tar.gz) script. 
The installer works fine in the real server, it extracts the file and runs the server service. However, when I run the installer on dockerized Ubuntu the installer is complete but seems like doesn't add anything. doesn't extract the file and doesn't start the server service.

Is there a difference between the real Ubuntu server and dockerized server? apart from it is docker and maybe it minimized? What is missing in dockerized server?

Here's what I've tried to install the server in Ubuntu docker interactively

```
$ docker run -it --name ubuntu_test ubuntu:16.04
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y curl 
$ curl http://deluxeaccounting.com/download/accurate/v5/fb64linux/FirebirdACCURATE-2.5.4.amd64.tar.gz --output accurate.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf accurate.tar.gz
$ ./FirebirdACCURATE-2.5.4.amd64/install.sh
```

## UPDATE

turns out I forget to cd first before installing the server,
before I ran the `install.sh` I changed the directory to `FirebirdACCURATE-2.5.4.amd64`. This changed the title of this question.

```
$ cd /FirebirdACCURATE-2.5.4.amd64/
$ ./install.sh
```

this works, so what is the difference for running a command inside a directory different and outside the directory?

Answer (score 0):

You did not show error messages you are getting, but best guess is install.sh uses  other files in its directory/subdirectories using relative path. And when you run it from a directory one level higher, it has no idea where to find those files.

Comment: I didn't show any error messages, because there isn't any. it just shows install completed whether I do it inside or outside the directory. Perhaps that might be right,